# How to find the pdf of a time-dependent parameter in a linear regression model with drift?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, kalman-filter, particle-filter

Suppose there exists a simple linear equation, where the dependent variable y(time series; measurements available) depends on x1 and x2. If the parameter multiplier of x2 is time dependent and the multiplier of x1 is a deterministic variable. How to find the pdf of the parameter multiplier of x2. Given the time series observations of y, x1 and x2. 
Please tell me how to solve this. Kalman/particle filter?

Comment: Do you need to find the value of the deterministic parameter as well or do you have it avalilable?

Comment: Yes I need to find them. I'm trying to do something based on this stat.duke.edu/~fei/samsi/Readings/06TomaReich.pdf but just on a simple linear regression model with time series output and input variable. If it helps, you can assume that the range of the deterministic parameter is given. Please help me. I'll be grateful. Thanks. @davidhigh